# Passing a JSON as prop in component React JS

Tags: reactjs

I have a component with another child component and I am passing a JSON state variable of the parent component as prop to the child component, but when I modify the JSON in the child component the state variable of the parent is been modified too. It doesn't have sense beacuse it just happens with JSON props, but if i use strings, numbers or arrays it works good and child state variables are just modified.
These are my components:

```js
class Child extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state={
            test2: this.props.data,
            
        }
        this.changeTextField = this.changeTextField.bind(this)
    }
    changeTextField(e){
        let data = this.state.test2
        data['name'] = e.target.value
        this.setState({test2: data})
    }
    render(){           
        return(
            <div> 
                <input type="text" value={this.state.test2['name']} onChange={this.changeTextField}/>                                  
            </div>  
        )
    }
}

class Parent extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state={
            test: {name: "hola"},
            editing: false,
        }
        this.edit = this.edit.bind(this)
        this.cancel = this.cancel.bind(this)
    }
    edit(){
        this.setState({editing: true})
    }
    cancel(){
        this.setState({editing: false})
    }
    render(){        
        return(
            <div>
                {(this.state.editing) ?
                     <React.Fragment>
                        <Child data={this.state.test}/>   
                        <button onClick={this.cancel}>cancelar</button>
                    </React.Fragment>   
                :
                    <React.Fragment>
                        <h1>{this.state.test['name']}</h1>
                        <button onClick={this.edit}>edit</button>   
                    </React.Fragment>
                }
            </div>
        )
    }
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    ReactDOM.render(<Parent/>, document.getElementById("app"))
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script> 
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>  
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>
    
   
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <script src="parent.jsx" type="text/babel"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how JavaScript works with [Objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects). They are always passed by reference and the others (strings, booleans, numbers as you mentioned) are [primitives](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Primitive) meaning they are immutable.

There are many amazing answers on SO already regarding these:

1. [JavaScript by reference vs. by value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6605640/javascript-by-reference-vs-by-value)
2. [Is JavaScript a pass-by-reference or pass-by-value language?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/518000/is-javascript-a-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value-language)

**How do we get around this?**

In your snippet, where you say `data['name'] = e.target.value` you are still mutating the state object, which is surely a **Not To Do** in React. You can read upon [Power of not mutating content in React Docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/optimizing-performance.html#the-power-of-not-mutating-data).

You could create a copy of the `test2` and choose to mutate that instead:

```
const data = {...this.state.test2};
data['name'] = e.target.value
```

But there is a chance that this function gets called programatically, this will run into an error because [`setState` is async](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-state.html#why-is-setstate-giving-me-the-wrong-value). Instead it gives us a functional version to deal with:

```
this.setState(prevState => ({
  test2: {
    ...prevState.test2,
    name: value,
  }
}));
```

Full Demo:

```js
class Child extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state={
            test2: this.props.data,
            
        }
        this.changeTextField = this.changeTextField.bind(this)
    }
    changeTextField(e){
        const value = e.target.value
        this.setState(prevState => ({
          test2: {
            ...prevState.test2,
            name: value,
          }
        }))
    }
    render(){           
        return(
            <div> 
                <input type="text" value={this.state.test2['name']} onChange={this.changeTextField}/>                                  
            </div>  
        )
    }
}

class Parent extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state={
            test: {name: "hola"},
            editing: false,
        }
        this.edit = this.edit.bind(this)
        this.cancel = this.cancel.bind(this)
    }
    edit(){
        this.setState({editing: true})
    }
    cancel(){
        this.setState({editing: false})
    }
    render(){        
        return(
            <div>
                {(this.state.editing) ?
                     <React.Fragment>
                        <Child data={this.state.test}/>   
                        <button onClick={this.cancel}>cancelar</button>
                    </React.Fragment>   
                :
                    <React.Fragment>
                        <h1>{this.state.test['name']}</h1>
                        <button onClick={this.edit}>edit</button>   
                    </React.Fragment>
                }
            </div>
        )
    }
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    ReactDOM.render(<Parent/>, document.getElementById("app"))
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script> 
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>  
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>
    
   
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <script src="parent.jsx" type="text/babel"></script>
</body>
</html>
```